# PyQt5 - How to return application to initial state after error handling with QMessageBox

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Just starting out with Python3 and PyQt5 and I'm kinda stuck here.

My main window takes two ticker codes as input and, after the user presses the Show Me! button, outputs ratio averages for each of them. I created a QMessageBox with an OK button that pops up when the user enters invalid ticker codes.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import good_morning as gm

import MainUI

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, MainUI.Ui_MyStockratios):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.home()

    def home(self):
        #If Show Me! button is clicked, go grab_user_input()
        self.show_me_btn.clicked.connect(self.grab_user_input)

    def grab_user_input(self):

        #Grab user input for QLineEdits
        self.ticker1_value = self.ticker1_label.text()
        self.ticker2_value = self.ticker2_label.text()

        #Fetch the ratios and place them in a dataframe
        self.kr = gm.KeyRatiosDownloader()

        try:
            self.kr_frame1 = self.kr.download(self.ticker1_value)
            self.kr_frame2 = self.kr.download(self.ticker2_value)

        #Error handling
        except ValueError:
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            msg.setText("Invalid ticker code")
            msg.setInformativeText("Please verify the data you entered and try again.")
            msg.setWindowTitle("Error")
            msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
            reply = msg.exec_()
            if reply:
                self.ticker2_label.clear()
                self.ticker1_label.clear()
                self.home()

             [...]

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here's my problem: I want the application to return to its' initial state after the user presses the QMessageBox's OK button, which means the QLineEdits must be cleared and the application must wait for the user to input new data and press the Show Me! button again. I cleared the QLineEdits with the clear() function, but can't seem to make the application wait for new user input.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference you're posted code is a bit incomplete.  I took some liberties to get a working example.  You can ignore most of the changes except for the button handler part.  You only need to connect the button once.  Your home() method is not needed.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
# import good_morning as gm

# import MainUI

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):#, MainUI.Ui_MyStockratios):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        # self.setupUi(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.show_me_btn = QPushButton('Show Me!', self)
        layout.addWidget(self.show_me_btn)
        self.ticker1_label = QLineEdit(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.ticker1_label)
        self.ticker2_label = QLineEdit(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.ticker2_label)


        # self.home()
        self.show_me_btn.clicked.connect(self.grab_user_input)

    # def home(self):
    #     #If Show Me! button is clicked, go grab_user_input()
    #     self.show_me_btn.clicked.connect(self.grab_user_input)

    def grab_user_input(self):

        #Grab user input for QLineEdits
        self.ticker1_value = self.ticker1_label.text()
        self.ticker2_value = self.ticker2_label.text()

        # #Fetch the ratios and place them in a dataframe
        # self.kr = gm.KeyRatiosDownloader()
        #
        # try:
        #     self.kr_frame1 = self.kr.download(self.ticker1_value)
        #     self.kr_frame2 = self.kr.download(self.ticker2_value)
        #
        # #Error handling
        # except ValueError:
        if 1:
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            msg.setText("Invalid ticker code")
            msg.setInformativeText("Please verify the data you entered and try again.")
            msg.setWindowTitle("Error")
            msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
            reply = msg.exec_()
            if reply:
                self.ticker2_label.clear()
                self.ticker1_label.clear()
                # self.home()

             # [...]

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```